# How to feed my while loop, conditionally?

Tags: shell

I have this script, called `Compare.sh`:

```
function Compare()
{
    echo 'Comparing here'
}

while read Dependency; do  
    
    Org=$(echo $Dependency | cut -d'/' -f1)
    Repo=$(echo $Dependency | cut -d'/' -f2)

    echo "Comparing $Repo ...";
    Compare $Repo
    
done <<< "$({ cat "$PWD/Dependencies"; echo; })"
```

The content of `Dependencies` is the list of dependencies

```
Infra/Logging
Infra/Geo
Infra/Accounts
Company/Services
Company/Employees
```

I call this function like `./Compare.sh` and it reads the `Dependencies` file and loops over it.

However, now I want to be able to give it only one item as a parameter. `./Compare.sh Infra/Accounts`. And if a parameter is provided, I want the loop to use that, basically, it's looping only once. Otherwise, it should read the `Dependencies` file.

Psudo code:

```
 done <<< if $1 then $1 else "$({ cat "$PWD/Dependencies"; echo; })"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to not bother with a file at all in the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

Compare () {
   # some code
}

while IFS=/ read -r Org Repo || [ -n "$Repo" ]; do
   printf 'Comparing "%s"\n' "$Repo"
   Compare "$Repo"
done
```

You would call this either like so:

```bsh
$ ./script <Dependencies
```

or like so:

```bsh
$ ./script <<<"Infra/Accounts"
```

or like so:

```bsh
$ some-command | ./script
```

or like so:

```bsh
$ ./script <<'END'
some/data
more/stuff
last/line
END
```

or in any number of similar ways.

The loop in this script reads the first two `/`-delimited strings into the variables `Org` and `Repo` from the script's standard input stream (`Repo` would get the rest of the line, even if there were further `/`-characters there, add a dummy variable to avoid this).  It's up to the user to pass the data they want to process on the input stream, and the script itself doesn't care how this is done.

The `-n` test is there in the case you pass a file with an unterminated last line (which is what it seems like you are trying to ensure with the way you provide the data to the script in your question, with that `echo`).

---

If you want to read from some file, `Dependencies`, *by default*, and only use the command line arguments as data if these are given, then use

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

Compare () {
   # some code
}

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    cat Dependencies
else
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
fi |
while IFS=/ read -r Org Repo || [ -n "$Repo" ]; do
   printf 'Comparing "%s"\n' "$Repo"
   Compare "$Repo"
done
```

That is, `cat` the file if there are no command line arguments, otherwise print the command line arguments on separate lines.  Whichever thing is done, the `if` statement provides the input to the same loop as in my first variation of the solution.

You would use this script as

```bsh
$ ./script
```

or as

```bsh
$ ./script 'some/data' 'more/stuff' 'last/line'
```

Note that this second script could be written as a wrapper around the first script, `script1`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    cat Dependencies
else
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
fi |
./script1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Mayhap, using (man bash) "Parameter Expansion; Use default values" and "command substitution". Try like

```
for Dependency in ${1:-$(< Dependencies)}
  do echo $Dependency
  done
```